# Basic AI eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, artificial-intelligence

I need some help in designing a simple AI for a tic tac toe game. I need the computer to place a 2 on the next available slot on his turn. It's for a beginner's eclipse programming class, but the professor has taken a sick leave and stopped answering questions! Any help would be greatly appreciated! I'm having trouble with the method at the end `ComputerInput[][]`. I get an error where it says `a[0] = a[1]`;

```
package lab15;

public class WinnerCheck {

    public static int PL_ONE = 1;
    public static int PL_TWO = 2;
    static Console console = new Console();
    static final int PAUSE      = 500;

    public static int[][] b = { { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 }, { 0, 0, 0 } };


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean done = false;

        while (!done) {
        printBoard(b);
        playerOneInput();
        computerInput(b);
        pause(PAUSE);
        detectWinner(b);
        console.clear();
    }
}


    public static void pause(int ms) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(ms);
        } catch (Exception ex) {

        }
    }


    public static void placePiece(int[][] b, int r, int c, int player) {
        b[r][c] = player;
    }

    public static boolean isWinner(int[][] b, int player) {
        // check for a horizontal winner
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            int count = 0;
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                if (b[i][j] == player
                    || b[j][i] == player ) {
                    count++;
                }
            }
            if (count == b[i].length)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    public static int detectWinner(int[][] b) {
        if (isWinner(b, PL_ONE)) {
            return 1;
        } else if (isWinner(b, PL_TWO)) {
            return 2;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public static void printBoard(int[][] b) {
        System.out.println("------");
        for (int[] row : b) {
            for (int element : row) {
                System.out.print(element + " ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
        System.out.println("------");
        System.out.println("winner: " + detectWinner(b));
    }


    public static void playerOneInput() {
        switch (console.getKey()) {
        case '1':
            placePiece (b, 0, 0, 1);
            break;
        case '2':
            placePiece (b, 0, 1, 1);
            break;
        case '3':
            placePiece (b, 0, 2, 1);
            break;
        case '4':
            placePiece (b, 1, 0, 1);
            break;
        case '5':
            placePiece (b, 1, 1, 1);
            break;
        case '6':
            placePiece (b, 1, 2, 1);
            break;
        case '7':
            placePiece (b, 2, 0, 1);
            break;
        case '8':
            placePiece (b, 2, 1, 1);
            break;
        case '9':
            placePiece (b, 2, 2, 1);
            break;
        }
    }

    public static int computerInput(int[][]b) {
    int a[]= {-1};
        for (int i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < b[i].length; j++) {
                if (b[i][j] == 0
                    || b[i][j] == 1 ) {
                    a[0] = a[1];
                }
                }
        }
        return a[];
    }   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You initialized A with one value. So it only has a length of 1. That means the only index at 0. You need to either add a default second value or change the declaration to int a[] = new int[2];

Comment: Okay, I changed it to int a[]= {-1, -1}; 
but now im getting an error on return a[]. Expression expected after this token [.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your method headder to return int[] instead of int. Your return statement should only return a. That should fix that issue.

Comment: in other words....your method should look similar to....

public static int[] method(){
 int array = new int[2];
 return array;
}

Comment: Sorry, I had to stop for a while to do a few things. I'm no longer getting an error but the method is just filling up the board with 2s. It should be placing a 2 on the next available slot on the board after I place a 1 on the board.